# Any way to manually generate a transform on an asset source?

Tags: assets, image-transforms, import

I imported all of the posts from a WordPress blog, using a regular expression to update the image URLs to their new location in a Craft Asset Source. However, many of the original photos are straight out of the camera - 2000x3000px or whatever. What I would like to do is use that same regex to update them to a transformed version: so /wp-content/uploads/2014/12/photo.jpg would become /media/blog/_fullWidth/photo.jpg. I already set up that replacement and it's working great.

The problem is that the "Full Width" transform hasn't been generated, and just calling the URL from a Rich Text field bypasses Craft, so it never gets generated. Short of manually re-adding every photo through Redactor with the transform, is there any way to force Craft to generate a particular transform on all the images in an asset source?

Comment: Might be easier (and less processor intensive) in the long run to just download all the images, run them through photoshops 'File>Scripts>Image Processor' in a batch, re-upload them, and update the assets index.

Comment: +1 for Douglas's suggestion. Running all of that through PHP/GD/Imagick is going to be a headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just make a temporary template that makes Craft generate them for you. And depending on how many these are, you better use `limit` and `offset` with your `craft.assets` call.

```
{% set images = craft.assets.source('myAssetSource').limit(50).offset(0) %}
{% for image in images %}
    <img src="{{ image.url('fullwidth') }}">
{% endfor %}
```